# Mover subpastas com python

Tags: python, python-3.x, diretório

Há algum tempo estive tentando criar um *script* Python para mover subdiretórios de determinada pasta para outra por exemplo:

```
root  
├── pasta1  
│   ├── pastaa  
│   └── pastab  
├── pasta2  
└── pasta3  
    ├── pastac  
    └── pastad
```

estive tentando sem sucesso fazer com que que meu script python pesquisasse os subdiretórios de minha pasta *root* sendo eles as pastas "pastaa, pastab, pastac e pastad" fossem movidas um diretório acima o diretório root. alguma ideia?

Comment: Pode inserir o código relevante que trabalhou até agora? Isso ajuda a ajuda-lo

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar [`pathlib.Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path) para percorrer as pastas e [`pathlib.Path.rename`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rename) para mover seus conteúdos para a pasta raiz.

Veja um exemplo:

```
from pathlib import Path

# path da pasta root
root = Path('./root')
subpasta = Path('./root/pasta_1/subpasta_a')

# dados
print(root)                  # 'root'
print(subpasta)              # 'root/pasta_1/subpasta_a'
print(subpasta.name)         # 'subpasta_a'
print(root / subpasta.name)  # 'root/subpasta_a'

# move subpasta para './root/subpasta_a'
subpasta.rename(root / subpasta.name)
```

No exemplo acima eu uso [`pathlib.Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path) para criar um *path* para a pasta `root` e para a subpasta `root/pasta_1/subpasta_a`, depois imprimo alguns dados para demonstrar o uso de [`Path.name`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.name) para pegar o nome do diretório e o uso do operador `/` para unir dois paths (veja a [PEP-0428](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0428/) para mais informações). E por fim, uso estes conceitos juntamente com o método [`Path.rename`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rename) para mover a subpasta para a pasta raiz.

Aplicando os conceitos acima ao seu problema, basta iterar no diretório usando [`Path.iterdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.iterdir) e usar [`Path.is_dir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.is_dir) para testar se o item iterado é uma pasta e mover seu conteúdo para `root`.

#### Código final

```
from pathlib import Path

# Pasta raiz
root = Path('./root')

# Percorre os arquivos e pastas do diretório `root`
for item in root.iterdir():
    if item.is_dir():
        # Percorre as subpastas de root (`pasta_1`, `pasta_2` e `pasta_3`)
        for subitem in item.iterdir():
            # Move o arquivo/pasta para o root
            subitem.rename(root / subitem.name)
```

---

Comumente o módulo [`os`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) é usado para este tipo de operação (como o @jsbueno [já mencionou em um comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/129209/mover-subpastas-com-python#comment818672_421228)), porém o módulo [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) contempla algumas operações comuns do módulo `os` como `rename`, `unlink`, `mkdir` ([entre outras](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#correspondence-to-tools-in-the-os-module)).

Neste caso estou usando pela facilidade do `Path`, não conheço a implementação do CPython para afirmar se há algum impacto de performance. Você também pode usar a função [`os.scandir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir) para percorrer os itens de um diretório, pois na sua documentação é afirmado que é mais performático que `os.listdir`, porém desconheço se esta função é mais performática que `Path.iterdir` ou `os.walk`.